# PHPUnit selenium Webdriver creating unique numbers after loop/error & restart

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I wish to create a unique number for a text field.
I can easily do it using:

```
 $this->core_id= date('Y-m-d-H:i:s') . ' CORE_ID';
```

This will create a unique number ( due to a date+time being unique ).

Though, isn't there another way to create a unique number even after I restart the selenium script?
So if it fails it will somehow remember what he entered previously and will NOT use the same number again.
So I assume I would have to store the used numbers or something?

The unique number can contain 10-20 numbers/letters or more I'm not to picky for that as long as it's unique and won't be used again even after the script failed and I have to restart it.

Comment: Are you using any data source for your tests or is it just stand alone Selenium scripts?

Comment: I'm using the facebook phpunit webdriver